# Wrap div.container around in foreach

Tags: php, html, containers, counter

Maybe a simple question, here it goes.
I have a simple php foreach script that output results fine. I need to wrap results with a container div for every second item. Example could be:

What script looks like

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, fdate, tdate FROM database');
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $date):
   $i++; 
   echo '<div class="range" data-range="'. $date->id .'">';
   echo 'test';
   echo '</div>';
endforeach;
```

Will output:

```
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
```

But i need following example: A container div wrapped around range for every second result. Like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
<div class="range" data-range="00000000"></div>
</div>
```

I tried with:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, fdate, tdate FROM database');
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $date):
   $i++; 
   if($i%2 == 0) {
     echo $i > 0 ? "</div>" : "";
     echo "<div class='container'>";
   }
   echo '<div class="range" data-range="'. $date->id .'">';
   echo 'test';
   echo '</div>';
endforeach;
```

But that will not work correctly with the result that I am looking for :)
Ideas? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet should get you what you need

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, fdate, tdate FROM database');
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $date):
   $i++;
   if($i%2 == 1) {
       echo '<div class="container">';
   }
   echo '<div class="range" data-range="'. $date->id .'"></div>';
   if($i%2 == 0) {
       echo '</div>';
   }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Nope. Sorry. It wraps it all all in a container, not like the wanted result :)
Above will output: <div class="container"><div class="range"></div><div class="range"></div><div class="range"></div><div class="range"></div></div>

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I messed up my own code - It worked. Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 1):

You were really close. :)

You want your container echoed outside of foreach loop.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, fdate, tdate FROM database');
$i = 0;
echo '<div class="container">';
foreach ($result as $date):
   $i++;
   echo '<div class="range" data-range="'. $date->id .'">';
   echo 'test';
   echo '</div>';
endforeach;
echo '</div>';
```

EDIT: Sorry, I have misunderstood your question, but still pretty simple.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, fdate, tdate FROM database');
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $date):
   $i++; 
   if($i%2 == 1) {
     echo "<div class='container'>";
   }
   echo '<div class="range" data-range="'. $date->id .'">';
   echo 'test';
   echo '</div>';
   if($i%2 == 0) {
     echo "</div>";
   }
endforeach;
```

EDIT 2: Wow, it's really not even that simple. You won't get closed last tag if there is an odd number of results. So, you actually want THIS:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, fdate, tdate FROM database');
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $date):
   if($i%2 == 0) {
     echo "<div class='container'>";
   }
   echo '<div class="range" data-range="'. $date->id .'">';
   echo 'test';
   echo '</div>';
   if($i%2 == 1) {
     echo "</div>";
   }
   $i++; 
endforeach;
if($result->Size() % 2 == 1)
{
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Though he should check if (!empty($result)) before outputting the first div#container... And he still needs the modulo test in there to output a new div#container with a close tag.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Yikes! Thanks :)

Comment: This will put all range classes in one container :/ :)

Comment: Yes! I made two edits since the initial answer. It wasn't that easy after all. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
define ('TEMPLATE_SUB_CONTAINER',   '<div class="range" data-range="%s">%s</div>');
define ('TEMPLATE_CONTAINER',       '<div class="container">%s</div>'); 

$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, fdate, tdate FROM database');
$i      = 0 ;
$buffer = '';

foreach ($result as $date):
   if ($i == 2) {
       flushBuffer($buffer);
       $buffer = '';
       $i=0;
   }
   $buffer .= sprintf(TEMPLATE_SUB_CONTAINER . '<br />', $date->id, 'test');
   $i++;
endforeach;
flushBuffer($buffer);

function flushBuffer($buffer) {
    if (strlen($buffer) > 0) {
        $buffer .= spintf(TEMPLATE_CONTAINER, $buffer);
        printf("%s", $buffer);
    }
}
```